# How can I write two letters with many spaces between them in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a pattern looking like this:
[click here, it's a capital A made out of A's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuO49.png)

I'm running into trouble getting the A's to space apart by four or five spaces (A____A). I have to use the format method, but I have no idea how to go about doing that. What is the easiest way? I tried to do something like this, but it says invalid syntax and I am very confused about how to do it right.

```
print('A',{:4d}.format('A'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the format in a string, as in `'{:4d}'.format(42)`.

Note that the `d` specifier expects an integer to be formatted, so `'{:4d}'.format('A')` would raise an error since `'A'` is a string, not an int.

Instead, you remove the `d`:

```
print('A{:>4}'.format('A'))  # or print(f'A{"A":>4}')
# A   A
```

The `>` will right-align the `'A'`, so that the spaces go in the middle.

---

A simpler way, without bothering with the formatting mini-language, is to simply insert the spaces:

```
print('A' + ' '*3 + 'A')
```

Comment: Alternatively: `'A{:4}A'.format('')` or `f"A{'':4}A"`

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! Sorry for the late response, I think I had a comment here previously but it disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

You can try

`print(f"{A:04}")`

Comment: `A` in this answer would be a variable name rather than a literal character and the zero would cause the output to be zero padded.